# Is there any way to clear the cache with specific cid?

Tags: 7, caching

I set some data in cache using `cache_set($cache_id, $temp_data, 'cache', CACHE_TEMPORARY);` from a custom module. It's cleared when I clear all the cache.

Is there any way I can clear that specific cached data using its ID?

Answer (score 1):

Despite the name, `cache_clear_all()` doesn't necessarily clear all the cache; it does so only when no parameter is passed to the function.

Usually Drupal core uses `cache_clear_all()` to clear all the cache. In some cases, it uses that function to clear a specific cache item, which is what Drupal core does in [`variable_set()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/variable_set/7.x), for example.

```php
function variable_set($name, $value) {
  global $conf;
  db_merge('variable')->key(array('name' => $name))
    ->fields(array('value' => serialize($value)))
    ->execute();
  cache_clear_all('variables', 'cache_bootstrap');
  $conf[$name] = $value;
}
```

In that code, the cache ID of the deleted item is *variables*, which is contained in the *cache_bootstrap* cache bin.

As side note, `cache_clear_all()` could be also used to delete all the cache items whose IDs start with the string passed as first argument. For example, `cache_clear_all('mymodule_', 'cache', TRUE)` would delete the cache items whose cache IDs are *mymodule_cached_data* or *mymodule_long_calculus_result*, for example. It won't delete a cache item whose ID is *user_cached_data*, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `cid` to [cache_clear_all()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x) to clear a specific bin.